# Topology - closures of intervals with the order topology

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

A question from my homework is

> Let $(X,<)$ be a totally ordered set. Let us examine $X$ with the order topology.
>
> a. Prove that $\overline{(a,b)} \subseteq [a,b]$ (where the overline denotes closure of the set). Give an example where the inclusion is strict.
>
> b. Give necessary and sufficient conditions such that $a\in\overline{(a,b)}$ and such that $b\in\overline{(a,b)}$

So I've managed a. easily enough. I think a proper example of strict inclusion would be a finite set - say $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ with the obvious order. Then $(2,4)=\{3\}$ so indeed $ \overline{(2,4)} = \{3\}$ and not $[2,4]$.

I'm stumped about the conditions though. Can anyone give me some help?
Thanks!

Comment: What is it that in your example guarantees that $2$ is not adherent to $(2,4)$?

Comment: I assume you mean the closure? Well trivially I would say that its the fact (2,4) itself is already closed. But under what conditions are (a,b) or [a,b) or (a,b] already closed sets?

Comment: Let's try it from a different angle. If $a$ has a neighbourhood that doesn't intersect $(a,b)$, what property must $(a,b)$ have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed a) follows from the fact that $[a,b]$ is closed, which is clear as the complement is the union of $\{x: x < a \}$ and $\{x: x > b\}$, which are open by definition of the order topology. The example of strictness is fine.

For $a$ to be in $\overline{(a,b)}$, we need every neighbourhood of $a$ to contain points $> a$. This happens exactly when $a$ has no right neighbour, i.e $a^{+} = \min \{x : x > a \}$ does not exist. Equivalently, there is no $a^{+} \in X$ such that $(a, a^{+}) = \emptyset$.

Examples of ordered sets where these exist, besides the obvious discrete ones like $\mathbb{Z}$ include $[0,1] \times \{0,1\}$ in the lexicographic ordering, where $(x,0)$ has right neighbour $(x,1)$.

For the right hand side $b$ we want of course for no left neighbour to exist, the definition of which should be guessable...