# Prob. 5, Sec. 17, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed.: How to prove this result in a general ordered set?

Tags: general-topology

Here's Problem 5 in the Exercises after Section 17 in the book, *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be an ordered set in the order topology. Show that $\overline{(a,b)} \subset [a,b]$. Under what conditions does equality hold?

Here $X$ is a non-empty set --- having more than one element --- with an order relation $<$ satisfying the following conditions:

(i) For each $x \in X$, it is not true that $x < x$.

(ii) For any two distinct points $x$ and $y$ in $X$, we have either $x < y$ or $y < x$, but not both.

(iii) For any elements $x, y, z \in X$, if $x < y$ and $y < z$, then $x < z$.

And the topology on $X$ has the following sets as a basis:

(i) all sets of the form $(a,b) = \{ \ x \in X \ \colon \ a<x<b \ \}$, where $a$, $b$ are any two elements of $X$ such that $a<b$.

(ii) all sets of the form $[a_0, b) = \{ \ x \in X \ \colon \ a_0 \leq x < b \ \}$, where $a_0$ is the smallest element of $X$ (if $X$ has any such element) and $b \in X$ such that $a_0 < b$.

(iii) all sets of the form $(a,b_0] = \{ \ x \in X \ \colon \ a<x \leq b_0 \ \}$, where $b_0$ is the largest element of $X$ (if $X$ has any such element) and $a \in X$ such that $a < b_0$.

My work:

> We show that if $x \not\in [a,b]$, then $x$ cannot belong to $\overline{(a,b)}$.

> Let $x$ be an element of $X$ such that $x \not\in [a,b]$. Then either $x < a$ or $b < x$.

> If $x < a$, then the open set $(-\infty, a)$ contains $x$ but does not intersect $(a,b)$.

> If $b < x$, then the open set $(b, +\infty)$ contains $x$ but does not intersect $(a,b)$.

> Here we define the set $(-\infty, a)$ as follows:
> $$(-\infty, a) \colon= 
> \begin{cases}
> [a_0, a) & \ \text{ if $a_0$ is the smallest element of $X$. } \\
> \bigcup_{y \in X \text{ and } y < a} (y,a) & \ \text{ if $X$ has no smallest element}.
> \end{cases}
> $$

> So $\overline{(a,b)} \subset [a,b]$.

But under what conditions does the equality hold? That is, can we state any necessary and / or sufficient condition(s) for the equality to hold?

Comment: Try a few examples of intervals in different ordered sets. For which does equality hold? What is the pattern?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/697946/4280 has my answer..

Answer (score 2):

No need  to go through all this. Just show that $[a,b]$ is a closed set containing $(a,b)$. Since $\overline{(a,b)}$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $(a,b)$,
$\overline{(a,b)}\subseteq[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument showing that $\operatorname{cl}(a,b)\subseteq[a,b]$ is fine, though you really should either define $(b,+\infty)$ or say that it’s defined analogously to $(-\infty,a)$.

For the second part of the question let’s look at what determines whether $b$ is in the closure; the reasoning for $a$ will be similar.

- Suppose that for each $x<b$ there is a $y\in(x,b)$; is $b\in\operatorname{cl}(a,b)$? (Note that this is how $\Bbb R$ behaves, for instance: $\frac12(x+b)$ is always strictly between $x$ and $b$.)
- What if there is an $x<b$ such that $(x,b)=\varnothing$? Can you think of a familiar linearly ordered set in which that can happen?

Comment: If, for each $x < b$, there is a $y \in (x,b)$, then yes, $b$ then is indeed in $\overline{(a,b)}$. And, if there is an $x<b$ such that $(x,b)=\emptyset$, then $b$ cannot belong to $\overline{(a,b)}$. An example is the set of integers. Am I right?

Comment: @Saaqib: Yes, that's right. In the second case we say that $x$ is the *immediate predecessor* of $a$ in the order; in the first case $a$ has no immediate predecessor.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Seems there is a small typo, corrected here: In the second case we say that $x$ is the immediate predecessor of $b$ in the order; in the first case $b$ has no immediate predecessor.