# Prob. 4, Sec. 31, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Satisfaction or otherwise of separation axioms as topology on a set become coarser or finer

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Here is Prob. 4, Sec. 31, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ and $X^\prime$ denote a single set under two topologies $\mathscr{T}$ and $\mathscr{T}^\prime$, respectively; assume that $\mathscr{T}^\prime \supset \mathscr{T}$. If one of the spaces is Hausdorff (or regular, or normal), what does that imply about the other?

My Attempt:

> We are given that 
>   $$
> X = \big( S, \mathscr{T} \big), \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad  X^\prime = \left( S, \mathscr{T}^\prime \right), \tag{Definitions 0}
> $$
>   where $S$ is a non-empty set, and also that 
>   $$
> \mathscr{T}^\prime \supset \mathscr{T}. \tag{0}
> $$
>
> **Hausdorffness:**
>
> If $X$ is a Hausdorff space, then so is $X^\prime$.
>
> Let $x$ and $y$ be any two distinct points of $X^\prime$. As $x$ and $y$ are also distinct points of the Hausdorff space $X$, so there exist disjoint sets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that $x \in U$ and $y \in V$, and as $U, V \in \mathscr{T}$ and $\mathscr{T} \subset \mathscr{T}^\prime$, so we can conclude that $U, V$ are in $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ also. Thus $X^\prime$ is also a Hausdorff space.
>
> However, if $X^\prime$ is a Hausdorff space, then $X$ need not be Hausdorff.
>
> For example, let 
>   $$ S \colon= \{ a, b \}, $$
>   and let 
>   $$ 
> \mathscr{T} \colon= \big\{ \emptyset, X \big\}, \qquad \mathscr{T}^\prime \colon= \mathscr{P}(X). 
> $$
>   Then $X^\prime = \left( S, \mathscr{T}^\prime \right)$ is of course a Hausdorff space, because the sets $\{ a \}$ and $\{ b \}$ are the disjoint open sets of $X^\prime$ containing the distinct points $a$ and $b$. However, $X = \big( S, \mathscr{T} \big)$ is not a Hausdorff space.
>
> **Regularity:**
>
> If $X = \big( S, \mathscr{T} \big)$ is a regular space, then $X^\prime = \left( S, \mathscr{T}^\prime \right)$ need not be regular.
>
> For example, let $S \colon= \mathbb{R}$, and let $\mathscr{T}$ denote the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ whereas $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ denote the $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> To show that $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology is regular, we note that one-point sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are closed. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $U$ be any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ containing $x$. Then there exists an open interval $(a, b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $a < b$, satisfying
>   $$ x \in (a, b) \subset U. $$
>   Now as 
>   $$
> a < x < b,
> $$
>   so we can find real numbers $c$ and $d$ such that 
>   $$
> a < c < x < d < b.
> $$
>   Then let us put
>   $$
> V \colon= (c, d).
> $$
>   This set $V$ is open in $\big( \mathbb{R}, \mathscr{T} \big)$, and also 
>   $$
> \overline{V} = [c, d] \subset (a, b) \subset U,
> $$
>   and hence 
>   $$
> \overline{V} \subset U.
> $$
>   Hence $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology is a regular space, by Lemma 31.1 (a) in Munkres.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264643/prob-3-sec-31-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-every-order-topology-is-regular) is a Math Stack Exchange post of mine that is relevant.

> However, $\mathbb{R}_K$ is not a regular space. Please refer to Example 1, Sec. 31, in Munkres.
>
> On the other hand, if we let $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ denote the lower-limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R}_l \colon= \left( \mathbb{R}, \mathscr{T}^\prime \right)$ is a regular space. Please refer to Example 2, Sec. 31, in Munkres.
>
> And, if $X^\prime = \left( S, \mathscr{S}^\prime \right)$ is regular, then $X = \big( S, \mathscr{T} \big)$ need not be regular.
>
> For example, let $S \colon= \mathbb{R}$, let $\mathscr{T}^\prime \colon= \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R} )$, and let $\mathscr{T}$ denote the $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $X^\prime$ is regular, but $X$ is not. Please refer to Example 1, Sec. 31, in Munkres.
>
> On the other hand, if we let $\mathscr{T}$ be the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, then $X = \big( \mathbb{R}, \mathscr{T} \big)$ is a regular space.
>
> **Normality:**
>
> If $X = \big( S, \mathscr{T} \big)$ is normal, then $X^\prime = \left( S, \mathscr{T}^\prime \right)$ need not be normal.
>
> For example, let $X$ denote the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers with the standard topology, and let $X^\prime$ denote $\mathbb{R}$ with the $K$-topology. Then $X$, being metrizable, is normal by Theorem 32.2 in Munkres, but $X^\prime$ is not regular (by Example 1, Sec. 31, in Munkres) and therefore not normal.
>
> And, if $X^\prime = \left( S, \mathscr{T}^\prime \right)$ is normal, then $X = \big( S, \mathscr{T} \big)$ need not be normal.
>
> For example, let $S \colon= \{ a, b, c\}$, and let 
>   $$ \mathscr{T} \colon= \big\{ \emptyset, \{ a, b \}, \{ b, c \}, \{ b \}, X \big\} $$
>   and 
>   $$ \mathscr{T}^\prime \colon= \mathscr{P}(X). $$
>
> Then $X^\prime$ is normal, because for any two disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$ in $X^\prime$, we can take $A$ and $B$ themselves to be the disjoint open sets containing $A$ and $B$, respectively.
>
> However, $X$ is not normal. the disjoint closed sets $\{ c \}$ and $\{ a \}$ have no disjoint open sets containing them.
>
> Thus we can conclude that if $S$ is any non-empty set, and if $\mathscr{T}$ and $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ are any topologies on $S$ such that $\mathscr{T}^\prime \supset \mathscr{T}$, then the Hausdorffness, regularity, or normality of $X^\prime = \left( S, \mathscr{T}^\prime \right)$ implies nothing about the Huasdorffness, regularity, and normality, respectively, of $X = \left( S, \mathscr{T} \right)$. And, the regularity or normality of $X$ implies nothing about the regularity and normality, respectively, of $X^\prime$. However, the Hausdorffness of $X$ does imply the Hausdorffness of $X^\prime$.

Is my solution correct in each and every detail? Or, are there issues?

Comment: It looks fine. (I’m assuming that the $K$-topology is the one that makes $\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ a closed set. I’ve the 1975 edition, which is quite different, and while he uses that example, he doesn’t name it.)

Comment: @Brian M. Scott yes, you're right. The $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is the one having as a basis all the open intervals and all the sets of the form $(a, b)\setminus K$, where $$K = \left\{ \frac{1}{n} \colon n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}. $$

Comment: Then it all looks good.

Answer (score 1):

It all looks fine, maybe you could rely more on earlier results, and reprove less, as a general tip to reduce the size of your write-ups.

Of course you can never conclude anything for the smaller topology from the property of the larger one here: any discrete space $(X,\mathcal{T}')$ is Hausdorff, regular, normal but we can take any suitable (automatically coarser) $\mathcal{T}$ on $S$ to show it need not be Hausdorff, normal or regular. No need for invention of new examples.

A finer topology than a Hausdorff can is always Hausdorff (because it's a "point-property"), but regular and normal can be lost because then we also introduce more *closed* sets that are to be checked for regularity and normality. The $K$-topology is standard for regularity (and thus also normality a fortiori), but for normality you could also have used the Sorgenfrey plane $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$ as Munkres describes it) vs the standard plane. That fits nicely into Munkres' collection of favourite examples.