# Let X be an ordered set in order topology. what conditions hold in order for closure (a,b)= [a,b]?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I said one of the condition for the equality to hold is that **[a,b] ⊂ closure of (a,b)**. And **the closure of (a,b) ⊂ [a,b]**. So, both should be subsets of one another. Moreover, **a,b ∈ closure of (a,b)**. Clearly, **a,b ∉ (a,b)**, which means that **a** and **b** are limit points of **(a,b)** Then, **(a,b)≠∅**. Since, **(a,b)≠∅**, then there is no immediate predecessor of **b** and no immediate successor of **a**.

Suppose that **a** had an immediate successor **s**, then the open ray **(-∞,s)** is an open set that contains **a** and doesn't intersect **(a,b)** because if **x ∈ (a,b)**, and **x ∈ (-∞,s)**, then **a < x < s**. Then, this would be a contradiction since **s** was suppose to be immediate successor of **a**.Then, **a** is not a limit point of **(a,b)**.

Similarly, suppose if **b** has an immediate predecessor **s**, then the open ray **(s,+∞)** is an open set that contains **b** and doesn't intersect **(a,b)** because if **x ∈ (a,b)** and **x ∈ (s,+∞)**, then **s<x<b**. Then, this would be a contraction to the fact that **s** is the immedaite predecessor of **b**. Then, **b** would not be a limit point of **(a,b).**

Thus, **closure (a,b)= [a,b]** if and only if there is no immediate predecessor of **b** and no immediate successor of **a**.

Is this correct?

Comment: You have a typo in the first sentence of the third paragraph, where you clearly mean $s$ to be the immediate **predecessor** of $b$, not the immediate successor, but otherwise it’s fine.

Comment: Sure. In other words: the set $(a,b)$ is nonempty and has neither a least nor a greatest element.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/697912/4280)